# apply decorator class to class method

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, signals-slots, python-decorators

Consider following decorator:

```
class connector(object):
    def __init__(self, signal):
        self.signal = signal
    def __call__(self, slot_func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            slot_func(*args, **kwargs)
        self.signal.connect(wrapper)
```

And following signal, and class with method I need to decorate:

```
from signalslot import Signal

update = Signal()

class manager(object):
    # SOME CODE CUT
    @connector(update)
    def update(self):
        print("I'm updating, yay!!!!")
```

As you can see I need to pass decorator some additional arguments, and in that case - signal I need to connect to.
How to pass self as well?

The reason I ask that, because it fails with following error if I try to apply this decorator to method, not a function:

> TypeError: update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

More specifically, if I try to emit the signal:

```
update.emit()
```

And yes, I use ["signalslot"](http://signalslot.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) in that project.

Answer (score 3):

`self` must be a *positional* argument, not a keyword argument:

```
def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #       ^^^^ You can't use "self=None" here.
    slot_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

If you need to differentiate between functions and methods, implement a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) instead.

However, if you are trying to connect a signal, you'll need to do so to *a bound method on each instance*. You'd be better of connecting your signals *at instance creation time*:

```
class manager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        update.connect(self.update)

    def update(self):
        print("I'm updating, yay!!!!")
```

When `manager.__init__` is called, you have have a new instance and it is then you can create *one* `self.update` bound method to receive the signal.

You can still use decorator for this, but you can, at best register *at class level* what functions can act as signal handlers; you'd have to enumerate all functions on your class at instance-creation time and bind all those signals then:

```
class connector(object):
    def __init__(self, signal):
        self.signal = signal
    def __call__(self, slot_func):
        slot_func._signal_handler = self.signal
        return slot_func
```

and a separate class decorator to wrap the `class.__init__` method:

```
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction

def connectsignals(cls):
    signal_handlers = getmembers(
        cls, lambda m: isfunction(m) and hasattr(m, '_signal_handler'))
    init = getattr(cls, '__init__', lambda self: None)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        init(self, *args, **kwargs)
        for name, handler in signal_handlers:
            handler._signal_handler.connect(handler.__get__(self))
    cls.__init__ = wrapper
    return cls
```

Decorate the class as well as the signal handlers:

```
@connectsignals
class manager(object):
    @connector(update)
    def update(self):
        print("I'm updating, yay!!!!")
```

The decorator then connects all handlers each time a new instance is created:

```
>>> class Signal(object):
...     def connect(self, handler):
...         print('connecting {!r}'.format(handler))
...
>>> update = Signal()
>>> @connectsignals
... class manager(object):
...     @connector(update)
...     def update(self):
...         print("I'm updating, yay!!!!")
...
>>> manager()
connecting <bound method manager.update of <__main__.manager object at 0x105439ac8>>
<__main__.manager object at 0x105439ac8>
```

You may want to check if the `signalslot` project uses weak references to track signal handlers however, as you'll either have a problem of circular references to any instances you create (where a `manager` instance is kept alive because a signal is still referencing a bound method to that instance), or where your signal handlers are cleaned up too early because your bound methods are stored in weak references, and thus won't have any *other* references to keep them alive.

Looking at the [`signalslot` source code](https://github.com/Numergy/signalslot/blob/master/signalslot/signal.py#L69), I see that the current iteration of the project uses hard references, so your `manager` instances are never going to be cleared unless you do so explicitly. For this reason alone I'd avoid using methods as signal handlers. Take a look at [using python WeakSet to enable a callback functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826700/using-python-weakset-to-enable-a-callback-functionality) if you want to use weak references instead.